# Show $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(k+a)\binom{n+k}{k}}=\frac{-\,n!}{(1-a)_n}\Big(\gamma+\psi(a)+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{k}\frac{(1-a)_k}{k!}\Big)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, special-functions

The conjectured identity of the title,
$$(C)\quad\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(k+a)\binom{n+k}{k}}=\frac{-\,n!}{(1-a)_n}\Big(\gamma+\psi(a)+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{k}\frac{(1-a)_k}{k!}\Big)$$
arose in an attempt to generalize a specific case of this identity for $a=1/2.$ (The symbol $(a)_k$ is the Pochhammer symbol.)  The specific identity I proved was
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(k+1/2)\binom{n+k}{k}}=\frac{n!}{(1/2)_n} \sum_{k=n}^\infty \frac{1}{k} \frac{(1/2)_k}{k!}=\frac{2^{2n}}{\binom{2n}{n}}\big(2\log{2} - \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{2^{-2k}}{k}\binom{2k}{k}\big)$$
This form is suggestive of $(C),$ for we can sum from 1 to $\infty$ and subtract the series tail and use the known summation,
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k} \frac{(1-a)_k}{k!}=-\gamma - \psi(a),$$
the two terms being Euler's constant and the digamma function, respectively.  The proof I prefer is one that doesn't require a knowledge of the RHS of $(C).$  For example, I'd prefer not to have it shown that both sides obey the same recursion relationship with a boundary condition.

Comment: It seems simpler to ask for proofs of the equivalent identities $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{k!}{(k+a)\,(n+k)!}=\frac1{(1-a)_n}\sum_{k=n}^\infty\frac{(1-a)_k}{k\,k!}$$

Comment: Isn't it enough to check that both the RHS and the LHS have the same residues at the simple poles $a=0, a=-1,\ldots, a=-n$?

Comment: Hello Jack.  This might be a valid approach, but can you do it without knowing the RHS of the equation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sum is an hypergeometric series :
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(k+a)\binom{n+k}{k}}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{n!k!}{(k+a)(k+n)!}=n!\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{\Gamma(k+1)}{(k+a)\Gamma(n+k+1)} $$
From the properties of the Hypergeometric function : http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunction.html
$$_3F_2(1,1,a;a+1,n+1;x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{\Gamma(k+1)\Gamma(k+1)\Gamma(k+a)\Gamma(a+1)\Gamma(n+1)}{\Gamma(1)\Gamma(1)\Gamma(a)\Gamma(k+a+1)\Gamma(k+n+1)}\frac{x^k}{k!} \\=a\:n!\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{\Gamma(k+1)}{(k+a)\Gamma(k+n+1)}x^k$$
With $x=1$ :

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{\Gamma(k+1)}{(k+a)\Gamma(k+n+1)}=\frac{1}{an!}\,_3F_2(1,1,a;a+1,n+1;1)$$

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(k+a)\binom{n+k}{k}}=\frac{1}{a}\,_3F_2(1,1,a;a+1,n+1;1)$$
A lot of relationships with other series and/or functions can be found in : http://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric3F2/

Also $\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{(1-a)_k}{k!k} = \frac{1}{\Gamma(1-a)}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{\Gamma(k+1-a)}{k!k} $ can be expressed in term of hypergeometric function.

With the help of WolframAlpha :

[image]

Replacing $x$ by $(1-a)$ and changing $n$ to $n-1$ leads to :
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{(1-a)_k}{k!k}= -\frac{\Gamma(n+1-a)}{\Gamma(1-a)n^2(n-1)!}\,_3F_2(1,n,n+1-a;n+1,n+1;1) - \frac{\Gamma(2-a)}{\Gamma(1-a)(1-a)}(\psi(a)+\gamma).$$

$$\gamma+\psi(a)+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{(1-a)_k}{k!k}= -\frac{\Gamma(n+1-a)}{\Gamma(1-a)n^2(n-1)!}\,_3F_2(1,n,n+1-a;n+1,n+1;1).$$

$$\frac{-n!}{(1-a)_n}\left(\gamma+\psi(a)+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{(1-a)_k}{k!k} \right) = \frac{1}{n}\,_3F_2(1,n,n+1-a;n+1,n+1;1) $$
And with the relationship between the two hypergeometric functions at argument=$1$ :
$$\,_3F_2(1,n,n+1-a;n+1,n+1;1) = \frac{n}{a}\,_3F_2(1,1,a;a+1,n+1;1) \tag 1$$
$$\frac{-n!}{(1-a)_n}\left(\gamma+\psi(a)+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{(1-a)_k}{k!k} \right) =\frac{1}{a}\,_3F_2(1,1,a;a+1,n+1;1) $$
With the relationship found above $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(k+a)\binom{n+k}{k}}=\frac{1}{a}\,_3F_2(1,1,a;a+1,n+1;1)$ one obtains :

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(k+a)\binom{n+k}{k}}=\frac{-n!}{(1-a)_n}\left(\gamma+\psi(a)+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{(1-a)_k}{k!k} \right)$$
which is the expected result.

Note : The most likely the relation (1) can be found in the literature. But I found no reference with only a too short search. On the other hand, my attempt to prove it analytically is not sufficiently rigorous to publish it.

Comment: I've scanned the 92 formulas I've on Wolfram's site for the ${}_3F_2$ evaluated at 1.  I've looked only for form: digamma + finite sum.  None of the Wolfram equations are like that.  It doesn't mean one of those formulas doesn't contain (C), but it may it will take some more work.  I'll dig into this approach when I get some more time.

Comment: See the addition to my previous answer.

Comment: Very nice to relate the RHS also to a 3F2.  It would have taken me a very long time to come up with this solution.  Thanks for your persistence.